# Where I could find this particular typrewriter-like font in lyx?

Tags: fonts, lyx

I'm writing my thesis in philosophy using Lyx and found out that most of them are written with this particular typewriter-like font. Could someone tell me where i could find this font? Does Lyx already provide a similar font?

Thanks to everybody[image]

Comment: do you have that in electronic form, or just on paper?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: This is not a [typewriter font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), but a [serif font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif).

Comment: Added the electronic version of the file